# Move @Html.Labelfor after the element

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>...)
<label>
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>...)
</label>
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>...)
```

But the final result in browser is:
 1)Element
 2)Hidden field
 3)Label

I need to fix this because a library I use needs the label to be immediately after the Checkbox.

Comment: do you get the same outcome when using @Html.LabelFor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you wrapping a `<label>` around a `DisplayFor`? Just use `@Html.LabelFor`.

Additionally. If you use the `@Html.CheckBox..` helpers they will render a hidden field after the checkbox. There is a good reason for this, but requires a lengthy example.

What you probably want is an editor template. This should get you started:

```
@model Boolean

<input type="checkbox" 
   id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")"
 name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")" />
```

The file for the code above is called "MyCheckbox" and is in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`

Model:

```
[UIHint("MyCheckbox")]
public bool MyProp { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.MyProp)
 @Html.LabelFor(x=> x.MyProp)
```

Output:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="MyProp" name="MyProp">
<label for="MyProp">MyProp</label>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried using @Html.LabelFor, I thought that <label> would give more flexibility, but no difference it seems.